# Need to save text to database in uppercase

Tags: asp.net, sql, textbox, formview, uppercase

I have an asp 4.0 page using a formview and C# code as needed. I have a textbox for "Street Name" add/edit. I have already used CSS text-transform:uppercase which converts the "look" of the text entered to uppercase however the underlying text is in the case used when typing. I need to save the text in my sql database as uppercase.

I have played with various forms of the FindControl on the backend with no luck. I can assign a new variable and populate with the textbox text then change the variable to uppercase (.ToUpper) however I cant determine how to write the variable back to the textbox field.

I hope someone know what I am talking about because I have found many instances of people wanting the textbox text in upper but have found nothing on the text being saved to the database being in all caps.

Here is the code :

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
    <title>Officer Advantage</title>
    <style type="text/css"> 
        .UpperCaseTextField
            {
                text-transform:uppercase;
            }  
    </style> 
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="~/ImageBase/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
        <link rel="icon" href="~/ImageBase/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:White">
    <form id="StreetFrm" runat="server" onload="LoadStreetRecords">
    <asp:Table ID="HeaderTbl" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="800px" Font-Names="sans-    serif">
        <asp:TableRow ID="HeaderRow_1" runat="server" Width="800px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Top">
            <asp:TableCell ID="HeaderCellLeft" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="250px" RowSpan="2"><asp:ImageButton ID="MemberStreetOfficerAdvantageBtn" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/ImageBase/OA_Logo.png" PostBackUrl="~/OA467/Default.aspx" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell ID="HeaderCellMiddle" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="300px" RowSpan="2"><asp:ImageButton ID="StreetHeaderLogo" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/ImageBase/Streets_Header.png" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell ID="HeaderCellRight" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="250px"><asp:Label ID="HeaderDayDateLab" runat="server"  Font-Bold="True" Font-Size= "Medium" ForeColor="#00AEEF" Text="Label"></asp:Label></asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow ID="HeaderRow_2" runat="server" Width="800px" HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Top">
            <asp:TableCell ID="HeaderRow2Col3" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Bottom" Width="250px"><asp:Label ID="HeaderLoginStatus" runat="server"  Font-Bold="True" Font-Size= "Medium" ForeColor="#00AEEF" Text="Welcome, Guest"></asp:Label></asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow ID="HeaderRow_3" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="800px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Top">
            <asp:TableCell ID="CellTop" runat="server" BackColor="#00AEEF" Height="10px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="800px" ColumnSpan="3"></asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
    </asp:Table>
    <asp:Table ID="StreetTbl_1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="800px" Font-Names="sans-serif">
        <asp:TableRow ID="StreetTbl_1_Row_1" runat="server" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="800px">
            <asp:TableCell ID="StreetTbl_1_Row_1_Cell_1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="250px">
                <asp:Table ID="StreetTbl_2" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="250px">
                    <asp:TableRow ID="StreetTbl_2_Row_1" runat="server" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="250px">
                        <asp:TableCell ID="StreetTbl_2_Row_1_Cell_1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="250px">
                             <asp:Label ID="StreetSelectLab" runat="server"  Font-Bold="False" Font-Size= "Medium" ForeColor="#00AEEF" Text="SELECT STREET"></asp:Label>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableRow ID="StreetTbl_2_Row_2" runat="server" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="250px">
                        <asp:TableCell ID="StreetTbl_2_Row_2_Cell_1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="250px" RowSpan="2">
                            <asp:ListBox ID="StreetSelectLbx" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="StreetDataSource1" DataTextField="StreetName" DataValueField="ID" Height="425px" Width="240px"  Font-Bold="True" Font-Size= "Medium" ForeColor="#2E3192" OnSelectedIndexChanged="StreetSelectLbx_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:ListBox>
                            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="StreetDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OA_ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [streetTbl] ORDER BY StreetName"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                </asp:Table>
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell ID="StreetTbl_1_Row_1_Cell_2" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="550px">
                <asp:FormView ID="StreetDetailsFvu" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="StreetDataSource2" DefaultMode="ReadOnly" OnItemUpdated="StreetDetailsFvu_ItemUpdated" OnItemInserted="StreetDetailsFvu_ItemInserted">
                <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Table ID="StreetTbl_3" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="550px">
                    <asp:TableRow ID="StreetTbl_3_Row_1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="550px"> 
                        <asp:TableCell ID="StreetTbl_3_Row_1_Cell_1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="550px" ColumnSpan="3">
                            <asp:Label ID="StreetLab" runat="server"  Font-Bold="False" Font-Size= "Medium" ForeColor="#00AEEF" Text="STREET NAME"></asp:Label>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow> 
                    <asp:TableRow ID="StreetTbl_3_Row_2" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="550px"> 
                        <asp:TableCell ID="StreetTbl_3_Row_2_Cell_1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="550px" ColumnSpan="3">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="StreetTxt" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size= "Medium" ForeColor="#2E3192" Width="540px" Text='<%# Eval("StreetName")%>' CssClass="UpperCaseTextField"></asp:TextBox>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableRow ID="StreetsTbl_3_Row_3" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="550px"> 
                        <asp:TableCell ID="StreetTbl_3_Row_3_Cell_1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="60px">
                            <asp:Label ID="StreetStateLab" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Size= "Medium" ForeColor="#00AEEF" Width="55px" Text="STATE"></asp:Label>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell ID="StreetTbl_3_Row_3_Cell_2" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="245px">
                            <asp:Label ID="StreetCountyLab" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Size= "Medium" ForeColor="#00AEEF" Width="235px" Text="COUNTY"></asp:Label>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell ID="StreetTbl_3_Row_3_Cell_3" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="245px">
                            <asp:Label ID="StreetCityLab" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Size= "Medium" ForeColor="#00AEEF" Width="230px" Text="CITY"></asp:Label>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableRow ID="StreetsTbl_3_Row_4" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="550px"> 
                        <asp:TableCell ID="StreetTbl_3_Row_4_Cell_1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="60px">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="StreetStateTxt" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size= "Medium" ForeColor="#2E3192" Width="55px" Text='<%# Eval("StreetState")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell ID="StreetTbl_3_Row_4_Cell_2" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="245px">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="StreetCountyTxt" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size= "Medium" ForeColor="#2E3192" Width="235px" Text='<%# Eval("StreetCounty")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell ID="StreetTbl_3_Row_4_Cell_3" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="245px">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="StreetCityTxt" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size= "Medium" ForeColor="#2E3192" Width="230px" Text='<%# Eval("StreetCity")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                     <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="550px"> 
                        <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell2" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="550px" ColumnSpan="3">
                            <br />
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"  Font-Bold="False" Font-Size= "Medium" ForeColor="#00AEEF" Text="RECORD ACTIONS"></asp:Label>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow> 
                    <asp:TableRow ID="StreetTbl_3_Row_5" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="550px">
                        <asp:TableCell ID="StreetTbl_3_Row_5_Cell_1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="550px" ColumnSpan="3">
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="StreetActionsEditBtn" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" OnClick="FormViewChangeToEditMode" ImageUrl="~/ImageBase/Edit.png" />
                            &nbsp;
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="StreetActionsInsertBtn" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" OnClick="FormViewChangeToInsertMode" ImageUrl="~/ImageBase/New.png" />
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                </asp:Table>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Table ID="StreetTbl_3" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="550px">
                    <asp:TableRow ID="StreetTbl_3_Row_1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="550px"> 
                        <asp:TableCell ID="StreetTbl_3_Row_1_Cell_1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="550px" ColumnSpan="3">
                            <asp:Label ID="StreetLab" runat="server"  Font-Bold="False" Font-Size= "Medium" ForeColor="#00AEEF" Text="STREET NAME"></asp:Label>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow> 
                    <asp:TableRow ID="StreetTbl_3_Row_2" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="550px"> 
                        <asp:TableCell ID="StreetTbl_3_Row_2_Cell_1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="550px" ColumnSpan="3">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="StreetTxt" runat="server"  Font-Bold="True" Font-Size= "Medium" ForeColor="#2E3192" Width="540px" Text='<%# Bind("StreetName")%>' CssClass="UpperCaseTextField"></asp:TextBox>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableRow ID="StreetsTbl_3_Row_3" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="550px"> 
                        <asp:TableCell ID="StreetTbl_3_Row_3_Cell_1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="60px">
                            <asp:Label ID="StreetStateLab" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Size= "Medium" ForeColor="#00AEEF" Width="55px" Text="STATE"></asp:Label>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell ID="StreetTbl_3_Row_3_Cell_2" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="245px">
                            <asp:Label ID="StreetCountyLab" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Size= "Medium" ForeColor="#00AEEF" Width="235px" Text="COUNTY"></asp:Label>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell ID="StreetTbl_3_Row_3_Cell_3" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="245px">
                            <asp:Label ID="StreetCityLab" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Size= "Medium" ForeColor="#00AEEF" Width="230px" Text="CITY"></asp:Label>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableRow ID="StreetsTbl_3_Row_4" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="550px"> 
                        <asp:TableCell ID="StreetTbl_3_Row_4_Cell_1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="60px">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="StreetStateTxt" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size= "Medium" ForeColor="#2E3192" Width="55px" Text='<%# Bind("StreetState")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell ID="StreetTbl_3_Row_4_Cell_2" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="245px">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="StreetCountyTxt" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size= "Medium" ForeColor="#2E3192" Width="235px" Text='<%# Bind("StreetCounty")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell ID="StreetTbl_3_Row_4_Cell_3" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="245px">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="StreetCityTxt" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size= "Medium" ForeColor="#2E3192" Width="230px" Text='<%# Bind("StreetCity")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="550px"> 
                        <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell2" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="550px" ColumnSpan="3">
                            <br />
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"  Font-Bold="False" Font-Size= "Medium" ForeColor="#00AEEF" Text="RECORD ACTIONS"></asp:Label>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow> 
                    <asp:TableRow ID="StreetTbl_3_Row_5" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="550px">
                        <asp:TableCell ID="StreetTbl_3_Row_5_Cell_1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="550px" ColumnSpan="3">
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="StreetActionsSaveBtn" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" CommandName="Update" ImageUrl="~/ImageBase/Save.png" />
                            &nbsp;
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="StreetActionsCancelBtn" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" OnClick="FormViewChangeToItemMode" ImageUrl="~/ImageBase/Cancel.png" />
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                </asp:Table>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:Table ID="StreetTbl_3" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="550px">
                    <asp:TableRow ID="StreetTbl_3_Row_1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="550px"> 
                        <asp:TableCell ID="StreetTbl_3_Row_1_Cell_1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="550px" ColumnSpan="3">
                            <asp:Label ID="StreetLab" runat="server"  Font-Bold="False" Font-Size= "Medium" ForeColor="#00AEEF" Text="STREET NAME"></asp:Label>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow> 
                    <asp:TableRow ID="StreetTbl_3_Row_2" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="550px"> 
                        <asp:TableCell ID="StreetTbl_3_Row_3_Cell_1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="550px" ColumnSpan="3">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="StreetTxt" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size= "Medium" ForeColor="#2E3192" Width="540px" Text='<%# Bind("StreetName")%>' CssClass="UpperCaseTextField"></asp:TextBox>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableRow ID="StreetsTbl_3_Row_3" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="550px"> 
                        <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="60px">
                            <asp:Label ID="StreetStateLab" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Size= "Medium" ForeColor="#00AEEF" Width="55px" Text="STATE"></asp:Label>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell ID="StreetTbl_3_Row_3_Cell_2" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="245px">
                            <asp:Label ID="StreetCountyLab" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Size= "Medium" ForeColor="#00AEEF" Width="235px" Text="COUNTY"></asp:Label>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell ID="StreetTbl_3_Row_3_Cell_3" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="245px">
                            <asp:Label ID="StreetCityLab" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Size= "Medium" ForeColor="#00AEEF" Width="230px" Text="CITY"></asp:Label>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableRow ID="StreetsTbl_3_Row_4" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="550px"> 
                        <asp:TableCell ID="StreetTbl_3_Row_4_Cell_1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="60px">
                            <asp:ListBox ID="StreetStateLbx" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size= "Medium" ForeColor="#2E3192" Width="55px" Height="298" DataValueField='StateAbbreviation' DataSourceID="StreetDataSource" DataTextField="StateAbbreviation" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("StreetState") %>'></asp:ListBox>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell ID="StreetTbl_3_Row_4_Cell_2" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="245px">
                            <asp:ListBox ID="CountyLbx" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size= "Medium" ForeColor="#2E3192" Width="235px" Height="298" DataValueField='CountyName' DataSourceID="CountyDataSource" DataTextField="CountyName" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("StreetCounty") %>'></asp:ListBox>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell ID="StreetTbl_3_Row_4_Cell_3" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="245px">
                            <asp:ListBox ID="StreetCityTxt" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size= "Medium" ForeColor="#2E3192" Width="230px" Height="298" DataValueField='CityName' DataSourceID="CityDataSource" DataTextField="CityName" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("StreetCity")%>'></asp:ListBox>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="550px"> 
                        <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell2" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="550px" ColumnSpan="3">
                            <br />
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"  Font-Bold="False" Font-Size= "Medium" ForeColor="#00AEEF" Text="RECORD ACTIONS"></asp:Label>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow> 
                    <asp:TableRow ID="StreetTbl_3_Row_5" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="550px">
                        <asp:TableCell ID="StreetTbl_3_Row_5_Cell_1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="550px" ColumnSpan="3">
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="StreetActionsInsertBtn" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" OnDisposed="FormViewChangeToEditMode" CommandName="Insert" ImageUrl="~/ImageBase/Save.png" />
                            &nbsp;
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="StreetActionsCancelBtn" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" OnDisposed="FormViewChangeToEditMode" CommandName="Cancel" ImageUrl="~/ImageBase/Cancel.png" />
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                </asp:Table>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                </asp:FormView>
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
    </asp:Table>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="StreetDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OA_ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [StreetTbl] WHERE ([ID] = @ID)" UpdateCommand="Update [StreetTbl] Set [Streetname] = @StreetName, [StreetState] = @StreetState, [StreetCounty] = @StreetCounty, [StreetCity] = @StreetCity Where [ID] = @ID" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [streetTbl] ([StreetName], [StreetState], [StreetCounty], [StreetCity]) VALUES (@StreetName, @StreetState, @StreetCounty, @StreetCity)">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="StreetSelectLbx" DefaultValue="42" Name="ID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="StreetName" Type="String" />
            </UpdateParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="StreetName" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <DeleteParameters>
            </DeleteParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="StreetDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionSTrings:OA_ConnectionSTring %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [statesTbl] ORDER BY StateAbbreviation">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="CountyDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionSTrings:OA_ConnectionSTring %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [countyTbl] ORDER BY CountyName">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="CityDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionSTrings:OA_ConnectionSTring %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [cityTbl] ORDER BY CityName">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of the CSS and backend code.

Use `style='text-transform:uppercase'` on the TextBox, and in your codebehind use `StreetTxt.Value.ToUpper();`

**Edit**

In that case you may be able to use the UPPER function in your commands in the ASPX:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180055.aspx

In StreetDataSource2 use:

```
UpdateCommand="Update [StreetTbl] Set [Streetname] = UPPER(@StreetName), [StreetState] = UPPER(@StreetState), [StreetCounty] = UPPER(@StreetCounty), [StreetCity] = UPPER(@StreetCity) Where [ID] = @ID"
InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [streetTbl] ([StreetName], [StreetState], [StreetCounty], [StreetCity]) VALUES (UPPER(@StreetName), UPPER(@StreetState), UPPER(@StreetCounty), UPPER(@StreetCity))"
```

Comment: I have tried using this however the Insert/Update code is in the asp code. How do I change on the backend/C# and have populate the StreetTxt textbox or the @StreetName being used to Insert/Update.

Comment: protected void StreetDetailsFvu_ItemInserting(object sender, FormViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox t;
        t = (TextBox)StreetDetailsFvu.FindControl("StreetTxt");
        if (t != null)
        {
            t.Text = t.Text.ToUpper();
        }
    }

Comment: See my edit..never tried this..but it may work. Use the UPPER Command in your Command statements

Comment: You know, like my answer said ;)

Comment: @Matt Yep...+1. Sometimes newbs need instruction on exactly where to put the code.

Comment: Thanks Ed... The good news is no errors, the bad news still not saving in uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

I'd normally shy away from this as I'd prefer to keep my business rules out of the database, but you can do it in T-SQL using the [UPPER() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180055.aspx) if you want to go that route.

If you want to use JavaScript instead, you could do it this way:

```
$('#<%=StreetTxt.ClientID%>').bind('keyup', function () {
    var uc = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
    $(this).val(uc);
});
```

Comment: I know of no other method to transform case to upper and have used upper() extensivly within sql. My problem is placing upper within asp or within backend code to change case to upper before insert/update. I tried Ed's idea wihtout success. Have been able to change case using upper() on backend with C# however cant take that changed case text back within my asp insert/update commands.

Comment: I'm kind of at a loss.  See my edit for yet another option: using jQuery to transform on the fly within the UI.  That way your Insert/Update commands don't have to worry about any other stuff... just take the value and save.