# How do I format the data in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I am using ASP.NET and SQL.

I have 3 columns in a table. I should populate the data in such a manner:

```
Date: 2014-09-22
Description1: xyz (this should be bold)
Description2 pqrs (normal paragraph)
```

after a horizontal tag  another data should appear

---

```
Date: 2013-09-22 
Description1: abcd (this should be bold)
Description2 qwe (normal paragraph)
```

I am able to populate the data in a `GridView` but I do not know how to format the data in this manner. I am new to ASP.NET.

Suggest me some tools or links or please help in writing code.

Comment: show what you've done so far, then we can help you from there.

Comment: use Template field in grid and use html for UI

Comment: Have a look here [Need to save text to database in uppercase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421917/need-to-save-text-to-database-in-uppercase) and [Inserting Data to Database using LINQ to SQL](http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2010/03/11/inserting-data-to-database-using-linq-to-sql.aspx)

Comment: @Jinesh Sam  - Use **`<asp:Repeater>`** for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your aspx/ascx you need to use `asp:Repeater` control, something like this:

```
    <asp:Repeater runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <p>Date: <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litDate"></asp:Literal></p>
            <p>Description 1: <strong><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litDesc1"></asp:Literal></strong></p>
            <p>Description 2: <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litDesc2"></asp:Literal></p>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <SeparatorTemplate>
            <hr />
        </SeparatorTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

In code-behind you should bind a collection of objects to this `Repeater`, and handle `OnDataBinding` event, where you should assign proper values to `asp:Literal` controls:

```
class DataItem
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public string Desc1 { get; set; }

    public string Desc2 { get; set; }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rptData.DataSource = new[]
        {
            new DataItem { Date = new DateTime(2013, 9, 30), Desc1 = "Test Desc 1", Desc2 = "Test Desc 2" },
            new DataItem { Date = new DateTime(2013, 9, 30), Desc1 = "Test Desc 3", Desc2 = "Test Desc 4" } 
        };

    rptData.ItemDataBound += OnItemDataBind;
    rptData.DataBind();
}

protected void OnItemDataBind(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var data = e.Item.DataItem as DataItem;

        var dateLiteral = e.Item.FindControl("litDate") as Literal;
        dateLiteral.Text = data.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

        var desc1Literal = e.Item.FindControl("litDesc1") as Literal;
        desc1Literal.Text = data.Desc1;

        var desc2Literal = e.Item.FindControl("litDesc2") as Literal;
        desc2Literal.Text = data.Desc2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks... its works... as i expected! ...   i modify the code like this <p>Date: <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litDate" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EDate") %>'></asp:Literal></p>

Comment: Yep, `DataBinder.Eval` works as well. I just prefer strong-typing over passing property names as string like in `DataBinder.Eval`.